# slick.js carousel how to remove numbers from slick-dots

Tags: jquery-plugins, slick.js

I've been looking through the slick-theme.css and I can't figure out how to hide the numbers inserted after the dots.

Can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. There shouldn't be any numbers inserted after the dots. Can you post a screenshot?

Answer (score 21):

The official solution is this according to slick.css

```
.slick-dots li button { 
   font-size: 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The best way would it be to create your own dots on a pseudo element, since the dots you see come from the `list-item`.

That's how slick is doing it for their own theme:

```
.slick-dots li {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    margin: 0 5px;
    padding: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.slick-dots li button {
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: transparent;
    border: 0;
    outline: none;
    background: transparent;
}

.slick-dots li button:before {
    content: '•';
    font-size: 22px;
    line-height: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: .25;
    color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Adding this worked for me

```
.slick-dots li button {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Numbers can be removed by using the text-indent property.

```
.slick-dots li button {
   text-indent: -9999px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove text of the button with javascript like this:

```
  var dotNums = document.querySelectorAll(".slick-dots button");

  function removeText(item) {
    item.innerHTML = ""; // or put the text you need inside quotes
  }

  dotNums.forEach(removeText);
```

Comment: You should add some explanation to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to remove the numbers from the dots.

**solution 1**

`setTimeout(function(){ const dots = document.querySelectorAll('.slick-dots li button') dots.forEach(dot=>dot.innerHTML="") },1000)`

.slick-dots li button doesn't happen to be part of the DOM when the page loads. it's is added after the slider start sliding.

**Recommended solution**

.slick-dots li button {
text-indent:-1000
}

Answer (score -3):

you can use jquery to remove the dots

[Docs](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)

```
$('.your-slider').slick({
   dots: false
});
```

Comment: I believe the OP is asking for how to remove numbers which appear after the dots, and not the dots themselves